# Accessing row data from Kendo Grid ClientTemplate

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, telerik

I am trying to embed a chart in a Kendo Grid Cell, following this example: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/faq#how-do-i-use-a-kendo-ui-widget-inside-a-grid-client-column-template

I have managed to embed the graph in the grid, but I am unable to find a way to bind to row data.

The ViewModel has properties for each bar value - but how do I bind to those properties (maybe some `#= ... #` expression?).
I expect something similar to this:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<ViewModel>()
    .Name("grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.DataID).Filterable(false);
        columns.Template(@<text></text>).ClientTemplate(
            Html.Kendo().Chart()
                .Name("chart#=DataID#")
                .Series(series =>
                {
                    series.Bar("\\#= FirstBarValue \\#");
                    series.Bar("\\#= SecondBarValue \\#");
                })
                .ToClientTemplate().ToHtmlString()
        );
    })
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource.Ajax().PageSize(20).Read(read => read.Action("Read", "Grid"))))
```

But the `FirstBarValue` and `SecondBarValue` are not properly evaluated, although `DataID` is. Maybe a different scope? I can only make it work with hard coded values.

Any suggestions?

Comment: We can not assign same datasource to both (Grid and chart).